# How to have several "develop" branches with git-flow?

Tags: git, latex, git-flow

I guess this is common in software development for instance with paid/free versions, however I am having this need while building my CV on latex. Let me illustrate first.

I have 3 types of CVs: projects, management and technical, and I maintain them in at least 3 languages: english, portuguese and spanish.

I am used to git-flow and I really like it, however I have only used it using just one develop branch. In this case I would like to have 9 develop branches: en-proj, en-mgmt, en-tech, pt-proj, pt-mgmt, pt-tech, es-proj, es-mgmt and es-tech.

Each feature would be started from a specific branch and finished to that branch instead from/to develop. Furthermore, each CV submission would have their own details, so ideally each of these "develop" branches commits would be a submission version. I guess there is no need to have a master branch.

I read these resources [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67568/how-can-one-use-git-flow-effectively-on-a-project-in-which-more-than-one-major-v) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579056/multiple-development-branches-with-git-flow) but I am looking forward to do this entirely using git-flow if possible.

Is there a way I can use git-flow as described? if so, how? From the links provided it is possible to create a feature from a branch using git instead of git-flow, but I guess it would be the same for finishing a feature and therefore git-flow would not be very useful, I would be ending using git alone.

If you could please answer with concrete examples of command-line snippets it would be ***very helpful!***

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There's no workflow for that.
But you can try to use the fork workflow without merging back the changes to the central rep, but already sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rodrigo, could you please elaborate your answer with some examples of command-line snippets for me to understand properly?

Comment: This tutorial explains the concept:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow
As I said before, it's a bad idea because it's like you're pretending you're multiple persons when you're not (as if there was each copy of you for each type of CV), and this workflow kind of fits that problem.
It's not a command solution, but more like a model solution.